# [android]: tabs at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read all the previously posted discussions on this topic.
I am new in android development and am creating tabs by referring the support.v4.FragmentTabs application.

Here two Fragment Layouts have been used.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html

I have a searchview and a scrollview containing a table in my main activity. below that I need to place the tab bar. please help me do this.
Thanks.